# How to setup a daily report of users which are sending more than a defined numer of email outside organization within 24h

Tags: exchange, scripting

I'm trying to create a script and schedule it on exchange in order to have a daily report for  users which are sending more than a defined numer of email outside organization within 24h.

I found this similar script but it is not the same scenario as the one i'm trying. Also i'm using Exchange 2016:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010

$output = Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -EventID "SEND" -ResultSize Unlimited | Group-Object -Property Sender | %{ New-Object psobject -Property @{Sender=$_.Name;Recipients=($_.Group | Measure-Object RecipientCount -Sum).Sum}} | Where-Object {$_.Recipients -gt 100} | Sort-Object -Descending Recipients | Format-Table -AutoSize Sender,Recipients | Out-String

Send-MailMessage -From sysadmins@example.com -Subject "Exchange senders report: $(Get-Date -UFormat '%a, %D')" -To sysadmins@example.com -Body $output -SMTP mail.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the script in the following similar thread is helpful to you:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
$output = Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -ResultSize Unlimited | where{$ .EventId -eq "SEND" -or $.EventId -eq "SENDEXTERNAL" -and $ .Recipients -notlike "*@contoso.com*"}
$result = $output | Group-Object -Property Sender
$report = $result | %{ New-Object psobject -Property @{Sender=$.Name;Recipients=($ .Group | Measure-Object RecipientCount -Sum).Sum}} | Where-Object {$.Recipients -gt 100} | Sort-Object -Descending Recipients | Format-Table -AutoSize Sender,Recipients | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -From admin@contoso.com -Subject "Exchange senders report: $(Get-Date -UFormat '%a, %D')" -To report@contoso.com -Body $report -SMTPserver smtp.contoso.com
```

Thread: **[How to setup a daily report of users which are sending more than a defined numer of email outside organization within 24h](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/522215/how-to-setup-a-daily-report-of-users-which-are-sen.html)**

Comment: Hello, i will try the script. Thank you so much for your reply. I have a question: this should output as a report all the users sending more then a defined numer of email toward one specific email address within last 24h ? Thank You

Comment: Do you mean the recipient of the report? If so, yes, this scripit will output entries of all external outbound emails within last 24h. If you want to specify an external recipient in the message tracking log, you can try the script in my new answer.

Comment: @Naldo Hi, it's been a while, is there update?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the specific email address to modify the recipient email address "user@contoso.com" in the following script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.SnapIn
$output = Get-TransportServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -Start (get-date).AddDays(-1) -ResultSize Unlimited | where{$ .EventId -eq "SEND" -or $.EventId -eq "SENDEXTERNAL" -and $ .Recipients -eq "user@contoso.com"}
$result = $output | Group-Object -Property Sender
$report = $result | %{ New-Object psobject -Property @{Sender=$.Name;Recipients=($ .Group | Measure-Object RecipientCount -Sum).Sum}} | Where-Object {$.Recipients -gt 100} | Sort-Object -Descending Recipients | Format-Table -AutoSize Sender,Recipients | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -From admin@contoso.com -Subject "Exchange senders report: $(Get-Date -UFormat '%a, %D')" -To report@contoso.com -Body $report -SMTPserver smtp.contoso.com
```